# A version of Urysohn's Lemma.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

For a compact set $K$ of $R^n $ and for an open neighborhood $U$ of $K,$ we know  that there exists a smooth, compactly supported function $f\in {\cal C}_c(R^n)$ supported in $U$ which equals $1$ on $K$. Can such function be chosen such that: $
\int_{_{U-K}}(f'(x))^2 dx \to 0, $ as $\mu(U-k)\to 0?$ where $f'$ is the derivative of $f$ and $\mu$ is the ${\cal L}$ebesgue measure.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "$\int_{_{U-K}}(f'(x))^2 dx \to 0$ as $\mu(U-k)\to 0$"?  Do you mean that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $U$ is such that $\mu(U-K)<\delta$, there exists $f$ supported on $U$ and $1$ on $K$ such that $\int_{_{U-K}}(f'(x))^2 dx <\epsilon$?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my question was not clear: Let the compact set $K$ be fixed. For any neighborhood $U$ of $K,$ I have a function $f=f_{_U}$. My question is: can I construct $f_{_U}$ in such away that:$$\forall \epsilon>0,\; \exists \delta>0;\; \mu(U-K)<\delta \Rightarrow \int_{U-K}(f_{_U}'(x))^2 dx < \epsilon.$$